# Querying from a non-Normalise Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays

i have the following, set of array and a mysql table ,table1

$arr1 = ("A0","A1","A2","A3","A4")
$arr2 = ("B0","B1","B2","B3","B4")

```
+----+-----------------+------+------+
| id | Col1            | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+-----------------+------+------+
|  0 | A0;B1;B2;       | x    | 9    |
|  1 | A0;B1;B2;A1;A2; | x    | 15   |
|  2 | A0;             | x    | 7    |
|  3 | B0;             | x    | 5    |
|  4 | C0;             | j    | 5    |
+----+-----------------+------+------+
```

is it possible that i can query the values in my table so that the final output will be something like this

```
    +----+-------+------+
    | id |  C31T | C32T |
    +----+-------+------+
    |  0 |  19   |  17  |
    +----+-------+------+
```

C31T and C32T was from this table

```
    +----+------+------ +-------+------+------+
    | id | Arr1 | Arr2  |  C31  | C32  | tot  |
    +----+------+-------+-------+------+------+
    |  0 | 1    | 2     |  3    |  6   | 3    |
    |  1 | 3    | 2     |  9    |  6   | 5    |
    |  2 | 1    | 0     |  7    |  0   | 1    |
    |  3 | 0    | 1     |  0    |  5   | 1    |
    +----+------+-------+-------+------+------+
```

Following eggyal solution i'm stuck up to this point

```
    SELECT   table1.id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) AS Arr1,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS Arr2,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) +
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS tot,
(COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element)/(COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element)+COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element)))*col3 AS c31,
(COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element)/(COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element)+COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element)))*col3 AS c32
FROM     table1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'A0' AS element
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A4'
  ) arr1 ON FIND_IN_SET(
    arr1.element,
    REPLACE(table1.Col1, ';', ',')
  )
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'B0' AS element
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B4'
  ) arr2 ON FIND_IN_SET(
    arr2.element,
    REPLACE(table1.Col1, ';', ',')
  )
WHERE    table1.Col2 = 'x'
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Comment: Not really possible (well, maybe with some quite hideous coding).
I would suggest putting the contents of those 2 arrays into a temporary table (one row per array element, so those 2 arrays would mean 10 rows), then join the temporary table with your existing table using a like. It will perform very badly though. A proper solution would require redesigning your table to get rid of the semi colon separated list, putting them in their own table with one row per element so that you can join between the tables easily.

Comment: @Kickstart, thank you, will try to redesign my table

Comment: modified my answer with something that might help you with extracting the data to a redesigned table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with [@Kickstart's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683990/in-array-equivalent-in-mysql#comment18786820_13683990)—you really should [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE associations (
  id      INT,
  element VARCHAR(2),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table1 (id)
);

INSERT INTO associations
  (id, element)
VALUES
  (0, 'A0'), (0, 'B1'), (0, 'B2'),
  (1, 'A0'), (1, 'B1'), (1, 'B2'), (1, 'A1'), (1, 'A2'),
  (2, 'A0'),
  (3, 'B0'),
  (4, 'C0')
;

ALTER TABLE table1 DROP Col1;
```

Then your query would be:

```
SELECT   table1.id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) AS Arr1,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS Arr2,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) +
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS tot
FROM     table1 JOIN associations USING (id)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'A0' AS element
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A4'
  ) arr1 USING (element)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'B0' AS element
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B4'
  ) arr2 USING (element)
WHERE    table1.Col2 = 'x'
GROUP BY table1.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af0f4/1/0)**:

```
| ID | ARR1 | ARR2 | TOT |
--------------------------
|  0 |    1 |    2 |   3 |
|  1 |    3 |    2 |   5 |
|  2 |    1 |    0 |   1 |
|  3 |    0 |    1 |   1 |
```

Without such a normalised schema, the "quite hideous coding" to which (s)he referred would be:

```
SELECT   table1.id,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) AS Arr1,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS Arr2,
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) +
         COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS tot
FROM     table1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'A0' AS element
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'A4'
  ) arr1 ON FIND_IN_SET(
    arr1.element,
    REPLACE(table1.Col1, ';', ',')
  )
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 'B0' AS element
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B1'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B2'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B3'
    UNION ALL SELECT 'B4'
  ) arr2 ON FIND_IN_SET(
    arr2.element,
    REPLACE(table1.Col1, ';', ',')
  )
WHERE    table1.Col2 = 'x'
GROUP BY table1.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbda8/1/0)**:

```
| ID | ARR1 | ARR2 | TOT |
--------------------------
|  0 |    1 |    2 |   3 |
|  1 |    3 |    2 |   5 |
|  2 |    1 |    0 |   1 |
|  3 |    0 |    1 |   1 |
```

#### UPDATE

Following your edit, you merely need to perform an outer query on this existing one:

```
SELECT SUM(Arr1/tot) AS C31T, SUM(Arr2/tot) AS C32T
FROM (

  SELECT   COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) * table1.Col3 AS Arr1,
           COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) * table1.Col3 AS Arr2,
           COUNT(DISTINCT arr1.element) +
           COUNT(DISTINCT arr2.element) AS tot
  FROM     table1
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 'A0' AS element
      UNION ALL SELECT 'A1'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'A2'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'A3'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'A4'
    ) arr1 ON FIND_IN_SET(
      arr1.element,
      REPLACE(table1.Col1, ';', ',')
    )
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 'B0' AS element
      UNION ALL SELECT 'B1'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'B2'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'B3'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'B4'
    ) arr2 ON FIND_IN_SET(
      arr2.element,
      REPLACE(table1.Col1, ';', ',')
    )
  WHERE    table1.Col2 = 'x'
  GROUP BY table1.id

) t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c290f/1/0)**:

```
| C31T | C32T |
---------------
|   19 |   17 |
```

Comment: not sure if this is against the rule here in SO, but i update the required output from my original post... I studied our existing table but cant readily normalised since some pages already depend on the current schema.. and changing it need to us another time to check existing pages. i followed eggyal solution, however im still stuck on how to get the value from Col3 in reference with the number of token found

Comment: Thank you, I was failing in trying to pull out everything i need in 1 query

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a play around.

Change your tables to something like this

```
Table1
+----+------+------+
| id | Col2 | Col3 |
+----+------+------+
|  0 | x    | x    |
|  1 | x    | f    |
|  2 | x    | g    |
|  3 | x    | k    |
|  4 | j    | k    |
+----+------+------+

Table2
+----+----------+------+
| id | Table1id | Col1 |
+----+----------+------+
|  0 | 0        | A0   |
|  1 | 0        | B1   |
|  2 | 0        | B2   |
|  3 | 1        | A0   |
|  4 | 1        | B1   |
|  5 | 1        | B2   |
|  6 | 1        | A1   |
|  7 | 1        | A2   |
|  8 | 2        | A0   |
|  9 | 3        | B0   |
| 10 | 4        | C0   |
+----+-----------------+
```

Then create a temp table for your query containing something like this:-

```
TempTable
+-------+----------+
| arrno | arrvalue | 
+-------+----------+
| arr1  | A0       |
| arr1  | A1       |
| arr1  | A2       |
| arr1  | A3       |
| arr1  | A4       |
| arr2  | B0       |
| arr2  | B1       |
| arr2  | B2       |
| arr2  | B3       |
| arr2  | B4       |
+-------+----------+
```

You can then use SQL like this:-

```
SELECT table1.id, COUNT(TempTable1.arrvalue), COUNT(TempTable2.arrvalue), COUNT(*)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.table1id
LEFT OUTER JOIN temptable TempTable1 ON table2.Col1 = TempTable1.arrvalue AND TempTable1.arrno = 'arr1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN temptable TempTable2 ON table2.Col1 = TempTable2.arrvalue AND TempTable2.arrno = 'arr2'
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Bit late, but was doing something else and thought it might help you as well.

Set up a table called integers with a single column called i. 10 rows with the values 0 to 9. You can then use that to split up you single field using the following SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Col1, ';', anInteger), ';', -1) AS Col1_split, Col2, Col3
FROM table1, 
(SELECT a.i*100+b.i*10+c.i AS anInteger FROM integers a, integers b, integers c) Sub1
HAVING Col1_split <> ''
```

This might help for copying the delimited field into another table (or if you were desperate you could use it as a subselect in you own SQL, rather than using the table directly).